# how to handle this in node js

Tags: node.js, kinvey

Currently I'm doing this:

filename : userOrder.js

```
const paymentGateway = require('./paymentGateway');

module.exports = {

        save: function() {

            // save user order record  
            return paymentGateway.makePayment();      

        },

        update: function() {

            // update user order record

        }

}
```

filename: paymentGateway.js

```
const payment = require('./payment');

module.exports = {

    makePayment: function() {

        // make payment
        return payment.save();

    }

}
```

filename : payment.js

```
const userOrder = require('./userOrder');

module.exports = {

        save: function() {

            // save payment record
            return userOrder.update();

        }

}
```

return userOrder.update(); -> this line gives an error "**TypeError: userOrder.update is not a function**"

Comment: Other code is only for save record nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using circular references between `payment.js` and `userOrder.js`. You can fix this by assigning a value to `module.exports` before you call `require`, like this:

**userOrder.js**

```
const userOrder = function() { };

module.exports = userOrder;

const paymentGateway = require('./paymentGateway');

userOrder.save = function() {
    // save user order record  
    return paymentGateway.makePayment(); 
}

userOrder.update = function() {
    // update user order record
}
```

**payment.js**

```
const payment = function() {};

module.exports = payment;

const userOrder = require('./userOrder');

payment.save = function() {
    // save payment record
    return userOrder.update();
}
```

No changes are required to `paymentGateway.js`, as this isn't part of a circular `require`.

Comment: Okay, let me try, i've also updated question.. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I'll update my answer to match the updated question.

Comment: @HirenMakwana no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
module.exports = {

    module.save = function() {

        // save user order record  
        return payment.save();      

    },

    module.update = function() {

        // update user order record

    }

    return module;
}
```